# jquery adding fadein to div blocks

Tags: jquery

I have a total of 4 div blocks , the div block can be 4 and sometimes it could be 3 or 2 or just 1 div block based on permissions.
I have 4 div blocks and each of the div block fade in with 100 delay.

How can i make them always have a 100 s delay fro each of the div blocks 
for example say  if div span4  is only by itself it should be 100 sec not 400. since 400 sec by itseld would be too long.

How can i do that?
My JS code

```
$('div.span1').fadeIn(100);
$('div.span2').fadeIn(200);
$('div.span3').fadeIn(300);
$('div.span4').fadeIn(400);

<div class="span1"></div>
<div class="span2"></div>
<div class="span3"></div>
<div class="span4"></div>
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard Isn't that script code shows what he has tried?

Comment: It's hard to know I suppose - the question in the title is about fadeOut - not fadeIn.

Comment: @jay - What's hard to know? `"My JS code"`...

Comment: @Lix look at the title of the post and then the content. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all of these div elements have similar class attributes, you'll be able to calculate the delay needed for each one within an `each()` function. Some code similar to this may be helpful -

```
var delta = 100;
$('div[class^="span"]').each(function(index,elem){
  $(this).fadeIn((index+1)*delta);
});
```

Note that I'm incrementing the index because [it is zero based](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

The selector I'm using (`$('div[class^="span"]')`) will match all the elements who's `class` [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `span`. I assume you'll have to customize this to your "real life" code.

Answer (score 3):

Give all the divs the same class, then do:

```
$('div.span').hide().each(function (i) {
   $(this).fadeIn((i+1)*100);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VKS2v/1/)**